# Como hacer una rayita en Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

maquetando un poco en Swift me encuentro que no se cual es el control para poder realizar el siguiente tipo de modelo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta ahora tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta seria como poder imitar la imagen de arriba

Agrege como me dijiste una view de 1 de altura pero la view queda muy por debajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
es la primera del todo la que el fondo esta como en blanco

pero la linea aparece abajo del todo

aparte de esto me aparece el color del edittext alguna forma de eliminarlo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es simple agregar una subvista para actuar como una línea. aquí te dejo un ejemplo guía:

Swift 4

```
 let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 320, height: 1.0))
 lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
 lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
 self.view.addSubview(lineView)
```

Objective C

```
UIView * lineview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,320,1)];
lineview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
lineview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:lineview];
```

O puede consultar este enlace para agregar CALayer o dibujar una vista

[¿cómo se dibuja una línea programáticamente desde un controlador de vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846413/how-do-you-draw-a-line-programmatically-from-a-view-controller) (Info en Inglés).

Comment: osea que deberia agregar una View debajo de cada caja y agregar ese codigo que me pasaste? disculpa soy bastante noob

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag si, también Puedes lograr esto en **Storyboard** .

Todo lo que tiene que hacer es arrastrar `UIView` con `height = 1`y `width` lo que sea bueno para usted (idealmente igual al ancho de la pantalla). Colócalo donde quieras que estén las líneas.

Comment: edite mi pregunta por favor si puedes ayudarme!

Comment: ya lo logre cambio el y a 0

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta extension de UIView

```
  public enum UIButtonBorderSide {
     case Top, Bottom, Left, Right, All
  }
extension UIView {

       public func addBorder(side: UIButtonBorderSide, color: UIColor,     width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.name = "border"
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

    switch side {
    case .Top:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: width)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    case .Bottom:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    case .Left:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    case .Right:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - width, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height)

        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    case .All:
        let topBorder = CALayer()
        let bottomBorder = CALayer()
        let rightBorder = CALayer()
        let leftBorder = CALayer()

        topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: width)
        topBorder.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

        bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

        leftBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        leftBorder.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

        rightBorder.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - width, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        rightBorder.backgroundColor = color.cgColor


        self.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
        self.layer.addSublayer(leftBorder)
        self.layer.addSublayer(rightBorder)

    }


  }

}
```

Y lo usas de esta manera

```
miTextField.addBorder(side: .Bottom, color: UIColor.blue, width: 2.0)
```